Why is the database empty?
I tried creating an in-memory H2 database using IntelliJ Community Edition.
The following are the dependencies in POM.xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

When I run the code, I get an error saying the database is empty.
The following is the class whose objects I'm trying to save in the database:
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
class Coffee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    @Column(nullable = false,columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String name;

    public A(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public A() {

    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

The following is a simple REST controller which saves and retrieves from the database.
@Repository
interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A,String> {}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/initial")
class DBSample {
    @Autowired
    private final ARepository zrepository;

    RESTApiDBController(ARepository zRepository) {
        this.zRepository = zRepository;
        this.zRepository.saveAll(new A("a"),new A("b"), new A("c"));
    }

    }

However, I'm getting the exception:
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement [Table "A" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into a (name,id) values (?,default) [42104-224]] [insert into a (name,id) values (?,default)]

The following is my application.properties file
spring.application.name=database
# H2 database configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

# Enable automatic table creation
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

# H2 console (optional, for manual inspection)
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console


The problem with the code posted is that it won't even compile. For example the constructor name can't differ from the class name. Please check and update the question with your actual code. Please also share the log of the startup.

Did you create a database?

Like Mar-Z mentioned, there are other issues also. 1. Constructor should match the entity class name, but in the Coffee class, it's named A(String name). It should be Coffee(String name). 2. In the repository and REST controller, you're referring to the class A, but your actual entity class is Coffee. 3. You're using String for the id field, but with the @GeneratedValue annotation, it’s better to use a numerical type like Long or Integer because GenerationType.IDENTITY works with auto-incremented numeric types.

Before using Spring and Hibernate, get your app running with simple direct JDBC.

i didn't work with h2, but try to changespring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create. It means spring will create new table with every launch. "update" used if you already created your table
